# Game for Android - don't see the obstacles

Tags: java, android

What I'm trying to do, is to write a game similar to "Flappy Bird", but in a vertical way. It means that we have the player and the obstacles that moving from up to down with the small gaps that player would be able to cross between the obstacle. I have the player (for now it's a small red rectangle) and I can move it by my finger, but my methods for obstacles aren't working, I can't see any of them coming down. I wrote something like this in the `ObstacleManager` class:

```
package com.example.sylwesterpilarz.quackattack;

import android.graphics.Canvas;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.lang.System;

public class ObstacleManager {
    private ArrayList<Obstacle> obstacles;
    private int playerGap;
    private int obstacleGap;
    private int obstacleHeight;
    private int color;

    private long startTime;

    public ObstacleManager(int playerGap, int obstacleGap, int obstacleHeight, int color) {
        this.playerGap = playerGap;
        this.obstacleGap = obstacleGap;
        this.obstacleHeight = obstacleHeight;
        this.color = color;

        startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        obstacles = new ArrayList<>();

        populateObstacles();
    }

    private void populateObstacles() {
        int currY = -5*Constants.SCREEN_HEIGHT/4;
        while(currY < 0) {
            int xStart = (int)(Math.random()*(Constants.SCREEN_WIDTH - playerGap));
            obstacles.add(new Obstacle(obstacleHeight, color, xStart, currY, playerGap));
            currY += obstacleHeight + obstacleGap;
        }
    }

    public void update() {
        int elapsedTime = (int)(System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime);
        startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        float speed = Constants.SCREEN_HEIGHT/10000.0f;
        for(Obstacle ob : obstacles) {
            ob.incrementY(speed*elapsedTime);
        }
        if(obstacles.get(obstacles.size() - 1).getRectangle().top >= Constants.SCREEN_HEIGHT) {
            int xStart = (int)(Math.random()*(Constants.SCREEN_WIDTH - playerGap));
            obstacles.add(0, new Obstacle(obstacleHeight, color, xStart, obstacles.get(0).getRectangle().top - obstacleHeight - obstacleGap, playerGap));
            obstacles.remove(obstacles.size() - 1);
        }
    }

    public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
        for(Obstacle ob : obstacles)
            ob.draw(canvas);
    }
}
```

I thought that maybe there is a problem in that `obstacles.remove` method, but deleting this won't change a thing. App starts, red rectangle shows up and obstacles are not. Is it possible that I did something wrong with the start point that my obstacles aren't show up?

Comment: `Is it possible that I did something wrong with the start point?` if you initialize currY to 0, do the obstacles populate onto your screen? If yes, then there is something wrong with the start point. Otherwise, it's some other problem.

Comment: @TreytenCarey - When I set `currY` to 0, then I get something like this:
`W/System.err: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=0; index=-1
W/System.err:     at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:310)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I solve the problem. It seems that this line:

```
obstacles.add(0, new Obstacle(obstacleHeight, color, xStart, obstacles.get(0).getRectangle().top - obstacleHeight - obstacleGap, playerGap));
```

cannot have a "0" value, somehow it needs some other plus value. After change it to "10" for example, it works like a charm. I thought that "0" is for the start point.